Does WDF have a related IO function like Linux mmap?
WDF IO queue seems Only have read/write/ioctrl,ect.
typedef struct _WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG {
 ULONG Size;
 WDF_IO_QUEUE_DISPATCH_TYPE DispatchType;
 WDF_TRI_STATE PowerManaged;
 BOOLEAN AllowZeroLengthRequests;
 BOOLEAN DefaultQueue;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_DEFAULT EvtIoDefault;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_READ EvtIoRead;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_WRITE EvtIoWrite;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_DEVICE_CONTROL EvtIoDeviceControl;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL EvtIoInternalDeviceControl;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_STOP EvtIoStop;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_RESUME EvtIoResume;
 PFN_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_CANCELED_ON_QUEUE EvtIoCanceledOnQueue;
 union {
  struct {
   ULONG NumberOfPresentedRequests;
  } Parallel;
 } Settings;
 WDFDRIVER Driver;
} WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG, *PWDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG;

but did not see mmap function?
So, I want to figure out a related way as mmap.
